# Order relation on two Disjunct sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

For the following relation we wish to prove that it is an order relation, thus we wish to prove reflexivity, transitivity and anti-symmetry.

Suppose $ (A,\sqsubseteq_A)$  and $ (B,\sqsubseteq_B)$ are partially ordered sets. If $A$ and $B$ are disjunct, we define the new relation $\sqsubseteq$ on $A\cup B$ as follows:

$x \sqsubseteq y$  if

($x,y \in A$ and $x \sqsubseteq_A y$

or $x,y \in B$ and $x \sqsubseteq_B y$)

or if ( $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.)

I figured that for reflexivity we state this for a disjunct set $A$ and $B$ so they do not have elements in common, so $a\in A$ and $a\in B$ is always false. Moreover if $a,a \in A$ we know since $ (A,\sqsubseteq_A)$  is a poset, $ a\sqsubseteq_A a$. similar argument when in B.
 Thus $ a\sqsubseteq a $ is always  true. But how do I go about the other two properties? It feels a bit... tricky

Comment: To prove transitivity for example, suppose $x \sqsubseteq y$ and $y \sqsubseteq z$. Then consider the cases of $x,y,z$ being in $A$ or $B$ - either they’re all in $A$, or $x$ is in $A$ and $y,z$ in $B$, or ...

Comment: or.. would follow a symmetry argument right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Anti-Symmetry)**

Assume $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$

Then

(1) $x,y\in A$ or

(2) $x,y\in B$

and it can not be that

(3) $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ or

(4) $x\in B$ and  $y\in A$

---

Assume (1) $x,y\in A$

Then $x=y$ since $\leq_A$ is a partial order.

---

Assume (2) $x,y\in B$

Then $x=y$ since $\leq_B$ is a partial order.

---

(3) is impossible since then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ contradicts $A$ and $B$ are disjunct

(4) is impossible (same reason as for (3))

---

**(Transitivity)**

Assume $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z$

Then

(1) $x,y,z\in A$ or

(2) $x,y,z\in B$ or

(3) $x\in A$ and $y,z\in B$ or

(4) $x,y\in A$ and $z\in B$

and it can not be that

(5) $x,z\in A$ and $y\in B$ or

(6) $x,z\in B$ and $y\in A$ or

(7) $x\in B$ and $y,z\in A$ or

(8) $x,y\in B$ and $z\in A$

---

Assume (1) $x,y,z\in A$

Then $x\leq z$ since $\leq_A$ is a partial order

---

Assume (2) $x,y,z\in B$

Then $x\leq z$ since $\leq_B$ is a partial order

---

Assume (3) $x\in A$ and $y,z\in B$

Then $x\leq z$ since $x\in A$ and $z\in B$

---

Assume (4) $x,y\in A$ and $z\in B$

Then $x\leq z$ since $x\in A$ and $z\in B$

---

(5) or (6) or (7) or (8) are impossible since this would contardict that $A$ and $B$ are disjunct

Comment: so structured and pretty....

Comment: This is something I wish I could "love" instead of simply upvote.

Comment: This exercise is not what math is about ..but just a small exercise

Comment: This helped me solve some other problem on my own, I just thought about your case analysis :)

Comment: excellent! welcome

Comment: Extra question; would restricting $x \in A $ and $y \in B$ or vice versa be enough to make this order linear?

Comment: The new order relation should be defined on $A\cup B$, correct? So I don't get what is meant by *restricting $x\in A$ or $y\in B$?*

Comment: Yes, but we can get $x,y \in A$ exclusive or $x,y \in B$, but $A$ and $B$ are posets, so not linearly ordered. I'm trying to understand what precisely would make this already defined order relation linear. I was thinking if we simply only compare elements pairwise from each set and not from the same set.

Comment: If we restrict our ordering to only comparing individual elements from each set, does that make it a linear ordering, Since the sets themselves are partially ordered, they are not linear by definition. We can also try to instead redefine our partial orders tin $A$ and $B$ to be a linear order.

Comment: As far as I know, a linear order should be total. So introducing restrictions on which elements are comparable will not lead to a linear order, correct?

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean, since we look at $A \cup B$ ANY two elements should be comparable....so the only way would be to make the initial partial orderings linear orders in our definition?

Comment: If you start with two totally ordered, disjuct sets $A$ and $B$ then you can define the *sum of the orders* in the above described way which is then again a total order on $A\cup B$.

Comment: Yeah exactly, linear order$=$total order.